# S4 method for ensuring dplyr distinct selects rows containing distinct S4 objects

Tags: r, dplyr, r-s4

I am implementing an S4 class called `Taxa`. Objects of class `Taxa` form a column in a `tbl_df`. For example:

```
 my_tbl <- tibble::tibble(taxa = list(Taxa(Taxon(family = "test")), Taxa(Taxon(family = "test1"))))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  taxa
  <list>
1 <Taxa>
2 <Taxa>
```

I would like to be able to select the distinct rows of `my_tbl` using `dplyr::distinct`. For example:

```
dplyr::distinct(my_tbl, taxa)
```

However this returns the error `Error: Unsupported type S4`. Is there a way to implement a method for `Taxa` that would help determine which elements of the column of `Taxa` objects are distinct?